# Why does `printf "%s"` concatenate two following strings together?

Tags: bash, printf

```
$ printf "%s" a b
ab$ printf "%s%s" a b
ab
```

I have some problem understand the format specifier for `printf`. If I am correct it is mostly the same as those for strings in the C programming language.

Why does the format specifier `%s` concatenate the two following strings together?

Why does  `%s` not mean that there is only one string to substitute it, and ignore the remaining string?

Why are the results for two strings under `%s` and under `%s%s` the same?

Comment: What do you get if you do `printf "%s 123" "hello" "world"`, yes it surprised me as well, but it is in the manual.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That’s [how `printf` is specified to behave](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

> The *format* operand shall be reused as often as necessary to satisfy the *argument* operands. Any extra b, c, or s conversion specifiers shall be evaluated as if a null string argument were supplied; other extra conversion specifications shall be evaluated as if a zero argument were supplied. If the *format* operand contains no conversion specifications and *argument* operands are present, the results are unspecified.

In your case, the `%s` format is repeated as many times as necessary to handle all the arguments.

```
printf "%s" a b
```

and

```
printf "%s%s" a b
```

produce the same result because in the first case, `%s` is repeated twice, which is equivalent to `%s%s`.

Comment: Does format specifier in C also work in the same or similiar way?

Comment: No, it doesn’t — it ignores extra arguments. Modern C compilers will warn about mismatches between the format string and the arguments.

Comment: @Ben in C, the `printf` function is a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic): all the parameters but the first are accepted via `...`. This means that unless told via the first argument how many are present (and which types), the function **can't ever** know what the caller has passed to it. In the shell the command knows exactly how many command-line arguments it has.

Answer (score 8):

If you supply more parameters to `printf` than the format string expects then the format string is repeated.

For example

```
$ printf "%s -- %s" a b c d e
a -- bc -- de --
```

We can see that the `%s -- %s` format is effectively repeated.

This can be useful; eg for formatting

```
$ printf "%s -- %s\n" a b c d e
a -- b
c -- d
e --
```